# How to speed up this linear search algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

This algorithm finds the first duplicate in an array and returns it, but, I'm getting a large execution time for largest arrays.

I've tried append first and then check but I failed

```py
a = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6,4,6]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
        if(a[i]in b ):
                print(a[i])
                break
        else:
                b.append(a[i])

if(a==b):
        print("-1")
```

This code either returns the first duplicate if found or return "-1".It's working, but how to make my code run faster ?

Comment: Using a `set` for `b` might help.

Comment: @hpaulj it will almost certainly make it faster, but won't help with memory errors.

Comment: Another minor step, iterate on `a` itself rather than the range.  `for i in a: ....`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, in the worse case how much memory does he need?  Space for `a` and a copy?  Any more?

Comment: What is the exact error/s you are getting and how many elements are in your largest array.

Comment: You'll have to be more clear. You say that the algorithm runs out of memory, but then you also say that you want it to run faster, which are two separate things. Using lesser memory does not make an algorithm run faster; in fact, it's often the opposite. Do you want the algorithm to use less memory, run faster, or both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a lazy solution that keeps track of visited elements in a set.

```
visited = set()
a = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6]
dups = (a for a in a if a in visited or visited.add(a))

# In [220]: next(dups)                                                   
# Out[220]: 4
```

This abuses the fact that `visited.add(elt)` returns `None`; since `visited.add` has a side-effiect, putting it inside a comprehension may be considered a code smell. A more readable solution would be to use a `for` loop inside a generator.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as what the OP has, but using a `set` instead of a `list`? The memory problem would persist regardless.

Comment: That's worked. `visited = set()
a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
dups = (a for a in a if a in visited or visited.add(a))
try:
    print(next(dups))
except:
    print("-1") `

Comment: @EvilTak the memory requirement is `O(N)` in either case, so we cannot do much. Of course, the speed improvement comes from replacing `O(N)` list search in the list with `O(1)` set lookup. As you hinted in your other comment, the original problem was probably unrelated to memory.